# Router in a private network

Tags: networking, router

The following shows the topology of a private network:

[image: topology of private network]

Suppose I am in the first level of hosts. Does installing router 3 in any way affect my network speed or any other factors? Is there any chance that I can access router 2 through router 2?

Also, I recently found there were some activities related to an application called NetCut which prevented me from accessing the web.  So for that reason I have made the MAC address of router 2 static in my system. What are the other forms of attacks that can any way degrade the network?

Comment: Link to image doesn't work

Comment: @Twisty Uploaded again

Comment: Some questions: **1)** Are the routers in your diagram true routers or are they more along the lines of residential routers (e.g. wireless routers)? **2)** Can you clarify the question _any chance that I can access the router 2 through router 2?_ Do you mean _any chance I can access **Router 1** through router 2?_ **3)** Can you clarify the question _What are the other forms of attacks that can any way degrade the network?_ As written its unclear what attacks you're concerned about. Thanks.